# Degrees of factors of pth cyclotomic polynomial in GF(q^n)

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Given p, q distinct primes, what are possible degrees of factors of $\Phi_p(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}[x]$? In the case of n=1, every factor has degree the order of q in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ so if q is primitive mod p then this should be irreducible. But what about the case when n > 1?

Comment: Do you know the proof of the assertion in your second sentence? Does it work when $\Bbb F_q$ is replaced by $\Bbb F_{q^n}$? If not, where does the proof fail?

Comment: The proof I worked out (not 100% sure if it's right), is that if you have a root $a$ in the algebraic closure of $F_q$ then using the frobenius automorphism gives d distinct roots (distinct mod p), where d is the order of q mod p, so any irreducible factor of $\Phi_p(x)$ has degree d in $F_q$. Extending to $q^n$ doesn't seem to change this argument, so would the factors still have degree d? Not the order of $q^n$ mod p? I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: In your notation, $\Phi_p$ splits in $\Bbb F_{q^d}$, so there certainly is some dependence on $n$. Have you worked out a specific example, say $q=2$ and $p=13$ (or $p=17$)?

Comment: You're right. I just went through a few examples in sage. It seems like $\Phi_p$ either splits or all its factors have degree d (order of q mod p). From some experimentation it seems like $\mathbb{F}_{q^d}$ might always be the splitting field, but I'm not sure how to go about proving that.